# Rounded corners for cell preview in the "insetGrouped" style (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, contextmenu, ios13

I have found an annoying problem with UITableView when it is in the `insetGrouped` style. When implementing `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath` method, it allows to peek-and-pop cell preview with context actions. Everything works fine except the feature when iOS rounds corners of the preview window.

[image: Corners are not rounded]

But corners become rounded if the table in every other style (plain, for example). Also animation in plain mode is more "smooth" and preview is scaled down a little bit.

[image: Corners are rounded]

I also found out that iOS rounds top corners for the first cell and bottom corners for the last cell in the `insetGrouped` style.

Has anyone encountered similar behavior of `UITableView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rounded corner for cell by implement method 'previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration'

```
- (UITargetedPreview *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration:(UIContextMenuConfiguration *)configuration {
NSIndexPath *index = (NSIndexPath *)configuration.identifier;
SharedTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];

UIPreviewParameters *parameters = [[UIPreviewParameters alloc] init];
parameters.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
parameters.visiblePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds cornerRadius:10.0];
UITargetedPreview *targetedPreview = [[UITargetedPreview alloc] initWithView:cell parameters:parameters];

return targetedPreview;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

**Swift version** [**Tài Mẫn Tiến** answer]

1. Make sure you are returning IndexPath correctly.

   ```
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: indexPath as NSCopying, previewProvider: nil,actionProvider: { suggestedActions in })
   ```
2. Swift code:

   ```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {


        guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? IndexPath else { return nil }
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellName else {

            return nil }

        let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
        parameters.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        parameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds , cornerRadius: 10.0)
        var targetedPreview: UITargetedPreview? = nil
        targetedPreview = UITargetedPreview(view: cell, parameters: parameters)

        return targetedPreview
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                              previewForDismissingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    return self.tableView(tableView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration: configuration)
  }
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? NSIndexPath else { return nil }
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? YourCellNameTableViewCell else { return nil }
    
    let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
    parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
    parameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius)
    
    let preview = UITargetedPreview(view: cell.contentView, parameters: parameters)
    return preview
  }
```

Don't forget to set in your cell:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    clipsToBounds = true
}
```

The same thing works for UICollectionViewCell,

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                              previewForDismissingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    return self.collectionView(collectionView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration: configuration)
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                          previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? NSIndexPath else { return nil }
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? YourCellNameCollectionViewCell else { return nil }

    let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
    parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
    parameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius)

    let preview = UITargetedPreview(view: cell.contentView, parameters: parameters)
    return preview
  }
```